# How to customize destination path of each dependency

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm trying to use Gradle to manage dependencies in non-Java projects.  The idea is to have a single, generic plugin that along with a project's gradle.build file will bring into the project any dependencies the project needs, placing each dependency where the project expects the files to reside.  Currently, it is working by placing them all in a /libs/ folder in the project, but that is not enough.  What I'd like to be able to do is to specify in the gradle.build file where to put the dependency in the project.

Here is a simple example:  I have a project that has been used for years as a component in other projects.  It is a real pain to update all projects when that core component code has been updated... each project repository has to have the new files committed (using SVN, specifically).  The files must reside in a particular directory so the ColdFusion framework (FW/1) correctly interacts with the code.

So what has been done is that core component is now in Artifactory and the gradle.build file pulls it down into the projects.  That would be the end of the story if it was the only dependency, but there are others that need to be pulled down and the code expects those to be in a different directory than that one component.  Each project will have different dependencies, and potentially different file structures (for example, our older apps are using the Fusebox framework).  So the ability to control where a dependency ends up as specified in the gradle.build file is what I'm after.

This is what I was hoping to be able to do:

```
dependencies {
    // exploded is a configuration that is added to this plugin

    exploded('com.foo:bar:2.0-SNAPSHOT@zip') {
        ext {
            moveWhat = ['app']
            moveWhere = 'assets'
        }
    }
    exploded('com.foo2:bar2:1.0-SNAPSHOT@zip') {
        ext {
            moveWhat = ['*']
            moveWhere = 'lib'
        }
    }
...
```

The hope was that I could pass directories/files into moveWhat that would then get placed into the directory specified by moveWhere, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to associate properties with each dependency.  I'm having trouble figuring out if this is even possible.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could this be done in a custom task, rather than the dependencies block?

Comment: Are you suggesting having a map elsewhere between the dependencies and where they should go?  And having the custom task be called using that map?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting having a task which puts dependencies where they need to go that runs as part of the build

Comment: But how would gradle.build tell the task where the dependencies go?  The goal is to have a generic plugin rather than a custom plugin for each project.  (Please let me know if that is not clear and I will update my question -- I am new to Gradle and what people's assumptions may be.)

Comment: Could you give a simple complete example/description of what you need to do in the question?

Comment: Sure... just updated my post... hope it's more clear, and thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a separate task to extract what you need from the configuration. Something like this:

```
task copyFromExploded(type: Copy) {
    into new File(project.buildDir, "assets")
    from (configurations.exploded)
    include "**/app"
}
```

Comment: How do I control where to copy per dependency, though?  I want it more dynamic than hard-coding it in the plugin.  (I edited the example code in case it wasn't clear before.)

Comment: I suppose you could use filter(Closure c) on the FileCollection object that represents the configuration. But that depends on if you have enough metadata to filter on (name of files etc).

Comment: configurations.exploded.filter{ file-> file.name.contains(pattern) }